# Python : While threading why does the conditional statement work differently?

Tags: python, multithreading, conditional-statements

I was trying to write a simple function and call it from a thread for different values. The function worked perfectly when called normally. But as soon as we call it from a thread the conditional statements inside the function do not work.

```
def func(count):
    print "In func count = {0}".format(count)
    if count == 3:
        print "If count = {0}".format(count)
        print "Sleeping as count = {0}".format(count)
    else:
        print "Else count = {0}".format(count)
        print "{0} so No sleep".format(count)
--------------------------------------------------
```

While calling the above function works perfectly.

```
print func(2)
print func(3)
print func(4)
```

Output is :

```
In func: count = 2
Printing Else Count = 2

In func: count = 3
Printing If Count = 3

In func: count = 4
Printing Else Count = 4


------------------------------
```

But while using the same function in a thread the behavior is different.

```
thread_arr = []
for index in range(2,5,1):
    thread_arr.append(threading.Thread(target=func, args=("{0}".format(int(index)))))
    thread_arr[-1].start()
for thread in thread_arr:
    thread.join()
```

Output is :

```
In func: count = 2
Printing Else Count = 2
In func: count = 3
Printing Else Count = 3
In func: count = 4
Printing Else Count = 4
```

Can anyone help why is the behavior different?

Comment: `"{0}".format(int(index))` is string, use integer `index` instead

Comment: Why did you insert that "{0}".format` call in the multithreaded version? Are you aware that `(thing,)` is a tuple and `(thing)` is just `thing` in grouping parentheses?

Comment: That is not the output I got for either example, please post output that is related to the code used.

Comment: @Haifeng Zhang
When I tried to do that, I used to receive the Exception.


Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: func() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

Comment: @user2357112 I did that because of the above Exception.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen I copy pasted the output as it is.

Comment: @orange_watch: That was a completely wrong move. The correct response would have been to replace `(index)` with `(index,)`.

Comment: @user2357112 Many Thanks.Your suggestion worked great. I was until now assuming there is no difference between (paramater) and (parameter,).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed the index as a string to the function, but you are checking for equality with an integer.

Also, doing `int(index)` is redundant. It's already an int.

You can check this by doing `print type(count)`

Edit: Here's an example of what you're doing.

```
 >>> x = "{0}".format(1)
 >>> x
 '1'
 >>> type(x)
 <class 'str'>
 >>> 1 == x
 False
```

Comment: Thanks. In the case when using a thread, I need to match it as a string.